# Table of content Latex problems

Tags: table-of-contents

i have a problem in the table of content in latex because the sections and subsections have styles. 
the problem is the style of the sections and subsections affected on the table of content like the picture below:
[image]

how can remove the style of sections in the TOC can anyone help me please?

Comment: How did you define the style of you (sub)sections?

Comment: Make the shortest posible example, without any irrelevant code for this issue (e.g, neither tables in text nor packages in preamble to make tables, etc.) and then post the complete source document, not  a snippet of the supposedly relevant code.

Comment: To elaborate on the other comments: LaTeX's default is an unstyled table of contents.  Since yours is styled, you must have done something to style it.  Unless you show us what you did to style it, the only thing we can tell you is "undo what you've done".  And posting your entire source for us to wade through will probably not get you much help.

Comment: This is how i style my (sub)sections 
\section{\LARGE\bf\color{myblue}{Overview}}         \subsection{\bf\color{myorange}Definition}

Comment: You want to avoid style commands within the `\(sub)section` commands, because those arguments end up being used elsewhere, as you've seen.  It's better to use a package dedicated to that end, such as `titlesec` in the accepted answer to the linked question.

Comment: Thank you Teepeemm, it works when i remove the style from the suction commands and generate a style for the sections using \titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bf\color{myblue}} but there is still just one problem the numbering of the sections still colored blue and orange how can i fix that? i'm using the following commands for the numbering:\renewcommand\thesubsection{\color{myorange}\thechapter.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand*\thesubsubsection{ \color{myorange} \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}

Comment: (You need to prefix the name with @ if you want the person to be pinged.  The post owner is automatically pinged.)  I'm not sure what you mean.  The numbering is blue and orange because you've renewcommanded them to be blue and orange.  What are you wanting to happen?  You may need to take a step back, and explain (in a new question?) what it is that you're trying to accomplish.  This is starting to turn into an XY problem (you ask about X, but it turns out you're really trying to do Y).